# How to get input value in beforeShowDays event of datepicker jquery?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i need to get value from input box via available function but it's show nothing, even no error

```
$( "#departure_date" ).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay:function(date) { available(date); },
    numberOfMonths:1,
    showWeek: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    showAnim: "slideDown"
});



function available(date)
{
    dmy = date;
    var code = $('#flyfrom_code').val();
    alert(code);
}
```

Comment: if you directly alert date in beforeshowday, does it alert ?

Comment: no it's showing nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your trying to do with this.  But to answer your question it looks like you are setting up your beforeShowDay function wrong.

```
$( "#departure_date" ).datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: available,
  numberOfMonths:1,
  showWeek: true,
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  showAnim: "slideDown"
});
```

Take a look at this example

http://jsfiddle.net/KkcNd/1/

returning `[true]` for the `date` will make it selectable and `[false]` non selectable.